# Invisible question

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, questions

I was seeing the unanswered questions in stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered

I saw something like this (Invisible question from user [termininja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3618581/termininja)
)
[image]

Any ideas on why [this now-deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138878/) was appearing like that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138878/, For less than 10k http://i.stack.imgur.com/qxN9I.png

Comment: Aren't ninjas supposed to be stealthy in everything they do? :^)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like somebody wanted a badge!

[image: Badge]

Or perhaps they were just testing.

They used [Zero-width spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) to create the seemingly empty title and body.

Comment: Unleash the meta effect!

Comment: Could also be someone testing something − doesn't have to be badge-hunting...

Comment: Isn't it much easier to just post some JavaScript and tag it with C++?

Comment: @rene Best is to ask a normal php question

Comment: Violated term 3 of [what passes as the SO TOS](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), "Don't be a jerk." Hope the badge was worth whatever sanction earned.

Comment: Oh my, they undeleted, closed it and deleted it. Some testing like @Carpetsmoker said. http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq4Y6.png

Answer (score 5):

Ah, you have to love some of our users. Yes, it was possible to get around some of the length checks using some invisible unicode combinations. I've closed a few more doors in this area in the next build. Ultimately, there's no point trying to play the "it must in every scenario be impossible to post a question with no visible title / text". If people want to post silly posts, there are a million ways they can do that *with* valid text, and deleting them works easily either way, with the advantage of helping us keep a clear history of who is being a nuicanse ;p

The specific tricks used this time won't work after the next deploy.